# How do I cross-compile gobject-introspection?

Tags: cross-compilation

I have successfully compiled gobject-introspection in a virtual machine (qemu-system-mipsel), but I'm having troubles with cross-compilation.

I have found [this article](http://nicola.entidi.com/post/cross-compiling-gobject-introspection/) on the topic, I'm trying to follow the instructions, modifying it for my platform, I use Python compiled for target platform and `qemu-mipsel` as INTROSPECTION_LAUNCHER.

In the end I get this message:

```
g-ir-scanner: link: /bin/bash ./libtool --mode=link --tag=CC mips-linux-gnu-gcc -o /gobject-introspection-1.48.0/tmp-introspectgaac9I/GLib-2.0 -export-dynamic -fno-strict-aliasing -Wsign-compare -Wcast-align -Wpointer-arith -Wnested-externs -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wchar-subscripts -Wall -g -O2 tmp-introspectgaac9I/p/gobject-introspection-1.48.0/tmp-introspectgaac9I/GLib-2.0.o -L/opt/lib -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -Wl,--export-dynamic -lgmodule-2.0 -pthread -lrt -lglib-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lgobject-2.0
libtool: link: mips-linux-gnu-gcc -o /p/gobject-introspection-1.48.0/tmp-introspectgaac9I/GLib-2.0 -fno-strict-aliasing -Wsign-compare -Wcast-align -Wpointer-arith -Wnested-externs -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wchar-subscripts -Wall -g -O2 tmp-introspectgaac9I/p/gobject-introspection-1.48.0/tmp-introspectgaac9I/GLib-2.0.o -Wl,--export-dynamic -pthread -Wl,--export-dynamic  -L/opt/lib /opt/lib/libgio-2.0.so -lz -lresolv /opt/lib/libgmodule-2.0.so -ldl /opt/lib/libgobject-2.0.so /opt/lib/libglib-2.0.so -lpthread -lrt /opt/lib/libffi.so -pthread -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/opt/lib -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/opt/lib
ERROR: can't resolve libraries to shared libraries: gobject-2.0
```

If anyone have ever cross-compiled gobject-introspection, please share a success story.